# How to preg match to parse the value addr: in this string

Tags: php, regex

I got a string of blockchain which is as of below

```
{"double_spend":false,"block_height":294529,"time":1396809215,"inputs":[{"prev_out":{"n":1,"value":68000,"addr":"1ZZZZhhdLL5ZKeD9gbakpt4J3vzGUMVHg","tx_index":53988341,"type":0,"script":"76a91406287de03de2b4cdd4095ce75c4101004677876b88ac"},"script":"76a91406287de03de2b4cdd4095ce75c4101004677876b88ac"}],"vout_sz":2,"relayed_by":"107.170.67.24","hash":"5f63a2dcbef2e534934b1919430d2ccafa030ec1f8011581a58b43b1d529db5e","vin_sz":1,"tx_index":54014213,"ver":1,"out":[{"n":0,"value":10000,"addr":"1L3ZER3u5qg8ZZ59c3Td9ecUWekESzCVnF","tx_index":54014213,"spent":true,"type":0,"script":"76a914d0e6208c2d26e09ff8b51c1b5ba12b4dcf66b71f88ac"},{"n":1,"value":48000,"addr":"1ZZZZhhdLL5ZKeD9gbakpt4J3vzGUMVHg","tx_index":54014213,"spent":true,"type":0,"script":"76a91406287de03de2b4cdd4095ce75c4101004677876b88ac"}],"size":258}
```

How do I parse the value of "addr": into an array

The print_r of the array should return

```
 [0]  1ZZZZhhdLL5ZKeD9gbakpt4J3vzGUMVHg
 [1]  1L3ZER3u5qg8ZZ59c3Td9ecUWekESzCVnF
 [2]  1ZZZZhhdLL5ZKeD9gbakpt4J3vzGUMVHg
```

Thank for helping!

Comment: This is json, you can simply convert it to an array and then access addr!!!

Comment: How did you decide on regex (not that one couldn't do that) instead of plain JSON parsing (which PHP supports) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of regex, use `json_decode` as your input looks like a `json`

```
$arr = array();

$json = json_decode($text);  // $text is the input
foreach($json->inputs as $x){
    array_push($arr, $x->prev_out->addr);
}
foreach($json->out as $x){
    array_push($arr, $x->addr);
}

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Yes it is json, sorry forgot that it is structure as json. Thanks for the help